# Get replied message on MessageEvent using discordgo

Tags: go, discord, discordgo

I am creating a Discord bot that should accept commands that react to a replied message.

What I mean is:

1. the user would reply to message `A` with a command (let this be message `B` replying to `A`)
2. the bot would get message `B` and find out message `A`'s ID so it can later analyse it.

I'm using the [discordgo](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/bwmarrin/discordgo) library for Golang. Tried [MessageReference](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/bwmarrin/discordgo#Message.Reference) without any luck.

All I've found so far was `Message.Type` which is indeed equals to [MessageType.MessageTypeReply](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/bwmarrin/discordgo#MessageType). So I know if a message is a reply but I can't get the ID of the replied message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were going in the right direction!

Reference to the original message is located in [`Message.MessageReference`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/bwmarrin/discordgo#Message) **field**.
[`Message.Reference()`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/bwmarrin/discordgo#Message.Reference) returns a reference object pointing to the message it was called on.

Hope this helps!